# Optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I want to optimize this query as it is taking long to execute almost a second

Here's the query:

```
IF Exists(
 Select CustFirstName From Customers
  Where (CustFirstName = InputCustFirstName)
     OR (CustLastName= InputCustLastName)
     OR (Email = InputEmail)
);
```

All these three columns have Unique index on it. and I have 765704 records in it.

This is the explain result set of my query :

```
----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys        | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Customers | ALL  | CustName | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 765704 | Using where with pushed condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------+
```

Can anyone assist me on how to optimize it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have enough indexes, it would seem.  There's only one `possible_keys`, where you probably need three.  Having a unique index on all three of them as a single tuple isn't enough.

Suppose you have all three columns indexed.  `Where (CustFirstName = InputCustFirstName) OR (CustLastName= InputCustLastName) OR (Email = InputEmail))` will usually frustrate the query optimizer.

Change the predicate using `OR` to one using `UNION`:

To paraphrase your query somewhat, you would change

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustFirstName = InputCustFirstName
OR CustLastName = InputCustLastName
OR Email = InputEmail
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustFirstName = InputCustFirstName
UNION
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustLastName = InputCustLastName
UNION
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Email = InputEmail
```

Answer (score 1):

One second to query a 3/4 million record index three times and return the union of all three queries?  Sounds reasonable unless you have a really fast server with 15K RPM SAS or SCSI disks.

You might try recoding it as a union of three separate queries, one for each column criterion.  That might allow it to use an index for each column.